# Unable to redirect to Gitlab's login page using Puppeteer in headless mode

Tags: gitlab, automated-tests, puppeteer, google-chrome-headless, headless-browser

I'm unable to access the sign-in page on Gitlab while test headless mode. The page shows this message

> This process is automatic. Your browser will redirect to your
> requested content shortly.   Please allow up to 5 seconds…

...but it never actually redirects to the login page.

Here's my code:

```
await page.goto('https://gitlab.com/users/sign_in')
await page.waitForSelector('#user_login')
```

How can I access the Gitlab login page?

Comment: any update on this ?

Comment: I was able to pass that screen using https://github.com/berstend/puppeteer-extra/tree/master/packages/puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth
But it doesn't work in headless for me.